# Python mapping removing values instead of changing them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Second Edit: The output of `map(type, raw_direct_data['Uom'])` and `map(type, mapping_df.Uom)` as requested by commenter.

`print(list(map(type, raw_direct_data['Uom'])))`

```
[<class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

`print(map(type, mapping_df.Uom))`

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

`print(map(type, raw_direct_data['Uom']))`

```
<map object at 0x000001BFAD9E2D60>
```

`print(map(type, mapping_df.Uom))`

```
<map object at 0x000001BFB2DD6250>
```

Edit: A screenshot of the output of my raw_direct_data dataframe. I believe this solves one problem and raises another. It seems that there are leading zeros in front of all the numbers, which means that my map isn't actually mapping anything to those values and instead just making them blank. These zeroes aren't present in the csv file I'm reading the data in from, are they possibly invisible on Excel/being added in somehow when I read the data? [image: Uom]

I have a program that uses mapping to change the values in a column of a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
d = dict(zip(mapping_df.Uom, mapping_df['Actual UOM']))
raw_direct_data['Uom'] = raw_direct_data['Uom'].map(d)
raw_direct_data = raw_direct_data[~raw_direct_data.Uom.str.contains("UOM" , na=False)]
```

The dataframe I'm using to create the map looks like this:

| Uom | Actual Uom |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | ML |
| 4 | UN |
| 7 | ML |
| 4U | GR |
| AL | ML |
| CA | UN |
| EA | DELETE THE ROW WITH THIS UOM |

Then I apply the map to another dataframe column to have it replace all the values in the column. The final line just deletes any row that's been replaced to say 'DELETE THE ROW WITH THIS UOM'.

The code above can correctly replace the entries that are strings (like AL and CA) but will not replace the entries that are integers (3 and 4), instead replacing them with a blank cell. Am I destroying this data somehow? I am new to using maps and am unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Can you include a small sample of your input dataframe and your expected output so it's easily reproducible for those providing an answer?

Comment: I suspect the type of `03` in column `Uom`, could you check it with `map(type, raw_direct_data['Uom'])`? If you could post the result of `map(type, mapping_df.Uom)`, that would be better.

Comment: Updated post with that information, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Post the actual snippet of your dataframe, not an image of it.